# System of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me please to solve this system of differential equations

[ \begin{cases}
\dot{x_{1}}=2x_{1}-x_{2}\\
\dot{x_{2}}=4x_{1}-2x_{2}-2t^{-3}
\end{cases}
]

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Extract $x_2$ from the first equation and plug into the second. This will give you a very simple second order differential equation in $x_1$.

I am sure you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: multiply first line by two and then subtract it from second line.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help ? Using Mathematica

```
 DSolve[{
 x'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t],
 y'[t] == 4 x[t] - 2 y[t] - 2 t^-3},
 {x[t], y[t]}, t]

{{x[t] -> -(1/t^2 + 4/t) t + (2 (1 + 2 t))/t + (1 + 2 t) C[1] - t C[2], 

y[t] -> 8 + (1/t^2 + 4/t) (1 - 2 t) + 4 t C[1] + (1 - 2 t) C[2]}}
```